# Kotlin - Extract underlying Class Type

Tags: generics, reflection, kotlin

So, I've been banging around in Kotlin reflection, and I can't seem to do the following:

```
object ThreadState {

    sealed class State {
object DANCE : State() {val validEvents: List<ThreadEvent> = listOf(ThreadEvent.Weave, ThreadEvent.Bob)}
object DUCK : State() {val validEvents: List<ThreadEvent> = listOf(ThreadEvent.Weave, ThreadEvent.Bob)}
object DODGE : State() {val validEvents: List<ThreadEvent> = listOf(ThreadEvent.Weave, ThreadEvent.Bob)}
.... Code
    }

.... Code
}
```

What I want to do is something like this:

```
val map = ThreadState.State::class.sealedSubclasses.map{ it to it.simpleName}.toMap()

map[ThreadState.State.DODGE]
```

And have it spit out the simple name of the class (in this case, DODGE).

The reason is because I can then simply reverse the map and get a value out from a name. I.e. `ThreadState.fromString("DODGE") // ThreadState.State.DODGE`

However, when I use ::sealedSubclasses, it gives a list of `<KClass <out ThreadState.State>>`

This is no bueno, because I cannot for the life of me find a way to get the `ThreadState.State` back out of any given element in the list of KClasses. I tried to run `it as ThreadState.State` but it told me that KClass can't be cast to ThreadState.State.

Any help would be massively appreciated.

In short - have a list of sealed classes that are singleton objects holding values. Need to make a map of the classes that conforms to `<ThreadState, String>`, where ThreadState is an instance of ThreadState.State and the string is just the simple name of the class.

I am really open to solutions - certainly doesn't have to be reflection, generics also welcome.

Comment: how should `State` ever be an instance of `ThreadState`?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand the question. ThreadState.State.Dance, for example, will allow access to the data for that class and also function as an enum.

Comment: `ThreadState` is an `object`. `State` is an inner class of `ThreadState`... otherwise there isn't any relation between the two... So you probably rather want a map of either `String` to `ThreadState.State` or viceversa...

Comment: do you want to get the actual objects? like `State.DODGE`, `State.DUCK` or do you want to get the classes of the objects? `sealedSubclasses` gives you the classes of it, not the objects...

Comment: @Roland I feel silly. I want to get the actual objects that inherit the State class.

Comment: my answer should now contain everything you need to know to get the object instances as well as the `validEvents`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
val stateMap = ThreadState.State::class.sealedSubclasses.asSequence()
  .map { it.simpleName to it.objectInstance } // note the objectInstance call
  .toMap()
```

Also note the documentation of [`objectInstance`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/object-instance.html#objectinstance):

> The instance of the object declaration, or `null` if this class is not an object declaration.

For testing purposes I added the following function to your `State`-class:

```
fun printMe() = println("class: ${this::class.simpleName} object: $this")
```

Now you can access the objects as follows:

```
stateMap["DODGE"]?.printMe()
// will then print the same as:
ThreadState.State.DODGE.printMe()
```

I question that it is worth to go that route, but you know the use-case, I don't... maybe also something like [delegated properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html) could be useful to you?

However: If you want to access `validEvents` you need to ensure that it is also a part of the `State`-class itself, i.e. you may need to add something like the following:

```
sealed class State {
  open val validEvents : List<ThreadEvent> = emptyList()

  // and then of course the subclasses need to override it:
  object DANCE : State() {override val validEvents: List<ThreadEvent> = listOf(ThreadEvent.Weave, ThreadEvent.Bob)}
```

Only then will you be able to call also something like:

```
stateMap["DODGE"]?.validEvents
```

Comment: WHOAAAAAA THIS IS PERFECT.

How did you know to make it an object instance?

Comment: to be honest: I guessed... If you look up [`objectInstance`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/object-instance.html#objectinstance) however, it becomes clear: *The instance of the object declaration, or `null` if this class is not an object declaration.*

Answer (score 1):

how about `map[ThreadState.State.DODGE::class]`? Or is it not applicable for you?

Comment: No, it totally works. 
When I do that and reverse the map, even if I return the object I can't access it's fields anymore. i.e. ThreadState.fromString("DODGE").validEvents
ValidEvents doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: @JapanRob I probably don't clearly understand what's the problem here. What does `fromString` method does? Is it only `when` statement returning instances? And what does it mean that `validEvents` doesn't exist anymore?

Comment: That's okay, I got the answer. Thank you though! And I'm upvoting your response because the syntax is correct.